# Divergent model versions in CoreData

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm working on a major update of an iOS application. Let's say that we have two branches, `develop` contains what's currently on the App Store and `feature/new_version` the one with the major update.

`feature/new_version` has a lot of model changes, so there's a new model version there that adds/removes entities, properties, etc. On the other hand, we had a couple of minor improvements and bugfixes in `develop`, that caused the creation of new model versions as well (these were updates submitted to the App Store too).

Now I'm stuck with two branches with very different data models. The question is: If I add the "missing" properties to the `feature/new_version` model, will core data be intelligent enough to do an automatic lightweight migration when I submit the major update to the App Store? Or should I download the data model used in `develop` and create a new model version in `feature/new_version` based on that one and re-add / remove all the changes since I first created the branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether automatic lightweight migration works depends on the nature of the changes from the old model to the new one. In your case, the differences between the currently released version to the one in your `new_version` branch.

If the changes are just adding new attributes, no problem, this is the scenario that automatic lightweight migration was designed for. If they're more complex, you're more likely to need some alternate migration scheme. You didn't detail the changes, but since you said that the new version *"adds/removes entities"* automatic migration doesn't sound very likely. Adding in the "missing" properties won't help if there are structural changes to the model. Core Data doesn't mind simple migrations but won't infer a refactoring of the model structure.

How you create the merged model doesn't really matter as long as it contains everything you need. If adding the new properties is all it takes, there's no reason to start over. What matters is that the resulting model is correct, not the steps you took to get it there.

The easiest way to tell whether automatic lightweight migration will work is often to just try it on a debug build and see what happens. Install the currently released version on a device, create some data, and then use Xcode to install the new version. Make sure that `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` and `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption` are both `YES` when adding the persistent store. If it works, great. If not, Core Data provides alternatives for when the model needs more than trivial changes.

Comment: As a matter of fact, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html states that "You can add, remove, rename entities.". The real question is if I need to include the same exact data model file used in the App Store, or which criteria coredata uses to find models.

Comment: Yes, you need to include the exact data model in the currently released version *and all previous released versions* in order for automatic lightweight migration to work.